# Excel Formula, IF statement to find number and assign percentage

Tags: excel

Not even sure if the "IF" statement will do what I want it to do but I've hit a brick wall and I'm not overly familiar with excel formulas.

What I'm trying to do is:
Cell A1 will have a number from 1-10 entered in it.
Cell B1 depending on the number in A1 will then display a certain percentage.

```
1 = -50%
2 = -40%
3 = -30%
4 = -20%
5 = 0%
6 = 10%
7 = 20%
8 = 30%
9 = 40%
10 = 50%
```

Comment: This is just a basic `VLOOKUP`, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

If the list of numbers you have given are correct, then you could use the formula `=IF(A1<5,(A1-6)*10,(A1-5)*10)`.

It looks odd that output jumps by 20% between 4 and 5, since the all the other differences are 10%. So on the off-chance that you really wanted a linear relationship with a difference of 10% each time, the simpler formula `=(A1-5)*10` would do the job.